# Show about 5 teens who all have elemental powers and turn into different humanoid creatures

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

I loved this show but it's really bugging me as I don't know the name... I remember it being animated and in the morning, in the year 2011 or around that.

The plot was about 1 teen girl with blonde hair and 4 boys who went to a school and were alerted when they had a mission. They went to this base thing where one of them would get picked for the mission, and then transform.

- the girl would have air power and turn into an angle like thing with blue and pink colours;
- and the other boys would be:

  - rock power (turning into rock monster)
  - earth power (turning into a tree-like thing)
  - fire power (having lava human form)
  - sea power (boy with a blue body and yellow long tentacle like hair).

Side note it's not *Captain Planet and the Planeteers* or  *The Knowhere Boys*.

Comment: Would that be an "angel-like" creature?

Answer (score 18):

*Gormiti: the Lords of Nature Return!* (2008)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1364483/):

> The show follows two brothers, Nick and Toby, who discover that they have the power to transform into powerful creatures known as Gormitis. Now it's up to them and their friends to save their world, and many others, from destruction.

The poster has characters fitting your description: Toby, Jessica, Lucas and Nick are Lords of (respectively) Sea, Air, Forest and Earth. No fire boy in the main crew, but the members  of the Lava Tribe are the main antagonists.

[image: transformed Gormitis]

The credits show the kids and their transformations.

---

Found with the Google query `animated tv show element powers transform "mission"`, the [first Google images result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC1Ai.jpg) looked promising (four kids with monster morphs in the background).

Comment: Following up from that, an image search for Gormiti does show up with a lava/fire boy front and centre.

Comment: @Separatrix [this guy](https://www.lopinionista.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/22050087_1833310306682567_3345375065520193935_n-1-e1538260420343.jpg)? Seems he's from a new 3D series. Or did you mean another?

Comment: There's [this chap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gormiti#/media/File:Gormiti_logo.jpg) as well

Comment: @Separatrix good point, yet another series! Gotta love franchise-based animation :D

Comment: (@Jenayah - What do you mean "franchise-based animation"?)

Comment: @BruceWayne when you make a series based on toys, to sell more toys. Cf _Transformers_ and a bunch of others... Generally speaking the shows end up being a mealstrom of messy series :D